# I just do not understand why this query does not pull results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Okay, this is the most simple query in the world, and it is somehow failing.

`SELECT * FROM kal_auth.dbo.Login WHERE ID = 'Zen' AND PWD = CONVERT(varchar,'0x9248FEFE237DB009')`

`0x9248FEFE237DB009` is not hex, although it looks like it. but it converts to "Password"

I know this row exists, and its only the password field which is not returning results, this was learned by isolating them and testing.

The PWD field is varchar(16).

I do not understand this.

Comment: You should always give an explicit length when converting to varchar - otherwise, SQL server uses surprising defaults. It's not the actual issue here, I believe, but worth noting.

Comment: What is the reason for the convert? Is that 'pseudo-hex' value not a string?

Comment: You don't mean the literal "Password" do you? Can't see it happening

Comment: Good point `SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(16),'Password')` gives `0x50617373776F7264`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,0x9248FEFE237DB009) -- returns ’Hþþ#}°
```

Not

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar,'0x9248FEFE237DB009') -- returns 0x9248FEFE237DB009
```

By encasing it in quotes it gets treated as a string not as binary data meaning the conversion to varchar doesn't do anything!

Comment: +1 thanks for the refresher Martin. One of those (many) functions that's not committed to memory yet.

Answer (score 3):

I may be missing something here...

The result of CONVERT(varchar,'0x9248FEFE237DB009') is the same '0x9248FEFE237DB009' with 18 chars, isn't it? So how could it be equal to a 16 char password?

Comment: Don't count the `0x`. That's just a prefix to denote binary data.

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying now (+1)